# Windows image fails to pull with error "failed to register layer"

Tags: azure-container-instances

I have image stored in AzureCI and I it fails to launch with following errors. I would assume since second entry is backing off of pulling image that image actually successfully downloaded but there is no additional information available about second error. Image is based of microsoft/dotnet-framework which is in turn based off windowsservercore image

`{
            "count": 58,
            "firstTimestamp": "2018-01-23T04:06:59+00:00",
            "lastTimestamp": "2018-01-23T12:37:39+00:00",
            "message": "pulling image \"cr.azurecr.io/id-poc:latest\"",
            "name": "Pulling",
            "type": "Normal"
          },
          {
            "count": 331,
            "firstTimestamp": "2018-01-23T04:07:15+00:00",
            "lastTimestamp": "2018-01-23T12:29:53+00:00",
            "message": "Back-off pulling image \"cr.azurecr.io/id-poc:latest\"",
            "name": "BackOff",
            "type": "Normal"
          },
          {
            "count": 1,
            "firstTimestamp": "2018-01-23T11:52:33+00:00",
            "lastTimestamp": "2018-01-23T11:52:33+00:00",
            "message": "Failed to pull image \"cr.azurecr.io/id-poc:latest\": failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: failed in Win32: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2) \nhcsshim::ImportLayer failed in Win32: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)",
            "name": "Failed",
            "type": "Warning"
          }, this continues 10 more times`

Comment: Have you verified this image builds locally and if so, is it still reproducing?

Comment: Yesm it works fine locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit 2: Turns out it was due to a base of unsupported Windows 1709.

Edit: Thanks for the clarification, made an assumption it was 1709 there. Let me look into it!

Unfortunately Windows 1709 images are not supported right now on Azure Container Instances. This will be fixed in the April time frame. In the mean time please use Windows images based on other versions as a work around - apologies for that! We're working on it!

Comment: This is not based off Windows 1709. It's based on `latest` servercore image which is based off LTSB stack

Comment: I just realized that it actually by default downloads 1709 for Fall Creators update for my base image even though I did not explicitly asked for it

Comment: Thanks for the confirm - could you try a version that isn't 1709 and lmk if that works?

Comment: Great, hope that the rest of the ACI experience is good! Stay in touch at aka.ms/aci/feedback !